# Как установить ссылку рубрики на изображение миниатюры в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Не получается установить ссылку рубрики на самой миниатюре, знаю, что за миниатюру отвечает `the_post_thumbnail()` находится он в **content.php**, но ссылку рубрики получается установить либо с вверху `the_post_thumbnail()` либо с низу.

Может надо что-то прописать в самом `the_post_thumbnail()`?

Пример картинки для наглядности.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код такой

Заголовок поста

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;
endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
            ?>
</header>
```

миниатюра изображения

```
<?php old_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

ссылка на рубрику и комментарии

```
<footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php old_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer>
</article>
```

old-название темы

Comment: Это твоя тема выводит "ссылку рубрики". Приведи код как она это делает.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено таким образом:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">  <!-- заголовок поста --> 
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;
        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
            ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header>
    <div class="post-blok">    <!-- Блок миниатюры поста и категории (ссылки рубрики) -->
        <?php if (!is_sticky()) { ?>
            <div class="thumb">
                <?php old_post_thumbnail(); ?>  <!-- old название моей темы -->
                </div>
                <div class="cat"><?php the_category(', ') ?></div>  
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="thumb">
                <?php old_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>  
    </div>  
</article>
```

стили css

```
/* размер миниатюры */
.wp-post-image {
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
}

/* миниатюра */
.thumb{
    clear: both;
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* категория (ссылка рубрики) */
 .cat {
    background: #9a1d0d;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -206px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.cat a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

миниатюра для поста устанавливается в админке, называется "Изображение записи".

результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]